# Get tag of UIButtons added in UIScrollView on Long tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

In my app i am adding uibuttons in uiscrollview as subviews. I want to get tags of the buttons on long press. My code is

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
longPress.delegate = self;
[gridScrollView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

I want to know that how can I get the particular button tag in this code

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get all the buttons from the subviews property

```
for (UIButton *eachBtn  in [gridScrollView subviews]) {
    if ([eachBtn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
         NSLog(@"Button Tag : %i",eachBtn.tag);
    }
}
```

If you want to pass a button's tag then set the same tag to gesture

```
longPress.view.tag = btn.tag
```

After that In your long press handler method take this tag

```
  NSLog(@"Button Tag : %i",longPress.view.tag);
```

Comment: Actually i don't need each button tag. I only want to get the tag of long pressed button.

Comment: Then you should add each button a gesture recogniser and get its view.

Comment: How can i get its view or particular button tag? Please help

Comment: Thats what i want. It's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't keep track of all the buttons added to the scroll view (e.g. by adding them into array), just enumerate all the subviews of the scroll view, check that current subview is a `UIButton` and get `subview.tag`

```
for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        // subview.tag …
    }
}
```

or, if you know the tag, use `-[scrollView viewWithTag:]`